# when volatile keyword is used to qualify a variable ,were is it stored?

Tags: c, embedded

In embedded systems volatile is used to let the compiler not to modify/optimize the variable, however what is the significance of using volatile for a local variable , when used for global variable it reside in data segment , what is purpose if used in local variable and will it be in stack.

Comment: There's probably very little reason to use it for a local variable.

Comment: Just a wild guess... You might create some threads and pass the address of your local variable to them. Then the content could be changed asynchronously.

Comment: `volatile` is relevant as soon as context switches come into play – on MCU typically between main routine and interrupt service routines or between different ISR. For variables that are accessed in both contexts `volatile` assures that values are updated immediately in memory and not only in the cache or registers, so that the updated value is immediately available in the other context as well. Similarly in multi-threaded contexts (when using an OS or multiple cores).

Comment: @Barmar With exception of a `static` local variable...

Answer (score 6):

First of all, scope and storage duration are different things. Just because something is declared at local scope, it doesn't necessarily have *automatic storage duration*, which is the correct term to use here. Meaning that where a local scope variable is allocated is handled automatically by the compiler.

There is no direct relation between `volatile` and where a variable is stored. Except `volatile` access implies that a memory access is necessary. Most often the compiler will not store automatic storage `volatile` variables in registers but instead on the stack, since they get an address that way. But none of this is required by the C standard.

Similarly, `volatile` variables need to be allocated in a region of memory which isn't pre-fetched to data cache, since caching will conflict with the value update upon access. Who is responsible to ensure this isn't always clear, the responsibility lands somewhere between the compiler and the programmer.

As for the purpose of using automatic storage `volatile` variables, there are many. Communicating with hardware registers, enforcing blocks against optimization on critical code, ensuring that a variable gets allocated on the stack so that it becomes watchable in a debugger etc etc.

Comment: Re “Similarly, `volatile` variables need to be allocated in a region of memory which isn't pre-fetched to data cache, since caching will conflict with the value update upon access”: This is not necessary if the hardware provides coherency and `volatile` is being used only for communication between different software, not for some memory-mapped hardware device. What constitutes access to a volatile object is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

The `volatile` keyword has the same purpose when used in local variables as in global variables.
The data will be stored in just the same manner as without the `volatile` keyword.

The purpose of `volatile` is always to avoid any compiler optimizations which might cause the variable not to be written or read from memory. The typical usage for global variables is of course if they are accessed from an interrupt for example, or written to or read by hardware (DMA or similar).

But there are good reasons for usage in local variables as well, for example a common way of implementing a small delay is something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++);
```

This code can be seen as useless, since the value of `i` is never used. Thus, with compiler optimizations activated, the compiler may choose to completely remove that loop. After all, that would be a good optimization as the loop only consumes time and does nothing really useful.

If you instead mark the variable `i` as `volatile`, the compiler will be forced into actually writing all those values to `i` so it doesn't remove the delay-loop.

Another common usage of `volatile` for local variables is if a pointer of said variable is passed to some function which uses it in the same way as the common usages of global variables.

Comment: A “delay loop” is not a good reason for using `volatile`, possibly except in rudimentary hardware where no other option is available. Re “Another common usage of `volatile` for local variables is if a pointer of said variable is passed to some function which uses it in the same way as the common usages of global variables”: What? If an object is modified by way of pointers to it, then other functions in the same thread see changes to the object by ordinary C semantics; `volatile` is not needed for that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have written applications where this type of delay is very useful, such as bit-banging some serial protocol as fast as possible, where only a few instructions of delay is suitable.  Regarding local variable; in the same thread, you are right. But if passed to other threads or an interrupt, `volatile` is needed.

Comment: While I agree that dirty "busy-delay" loops are horrible practice in microcontroller programming (use hardware timers instead), it's a good example for demonstrating when volatile is needed.

Comment: From the embedded system's perspective I once wrote this: [Using volatile in embedded C development](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102). Somewhat simplified as it doesn't mention things like DMA buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you don't want the compiler to make assumptions that may cause it to remove explicit reads or writes to a variable.

The empty loop is the obvious example, but another is where you might create "dummy" variables for debug purposes that you will only ever read or write in the debugger.  For example:

```
// Write without Read
int task( void )
{
    volatile int timeout_count = 0 ;

    for(;;)
    {
        if( eventWait( timout ) == TIMEOUT )
        {
            timeout_count++ ;

            // handle timeout
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            // handle event
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

There the without `volatile` the variable `timeout_count` could be optimised away since it is only ever written but never read.  In a debugger you might legitimately want to use the variable to determine how often the `waitEvent()` call has timeed-out.

Equally the same applies to circumstances where you might Read without Write:

```
// Read without Write
int errorTrap( int error_code )
{
    volatile bool stop = true ;

    logError() ;  

    while( stop ) ;

    return error_code ;
}
```

Again without `volatile`, the compiler may optimise away not only `stop` and make implement `while(true)`, but it may also remove the return statement as "unreachable" code.  With `volatile`, you may in your debugger either modify `stop` or set the program-counter to the `return` in order to return to teh caller and resume the code from the point of the error (where you might be able to patch the error manually in-order to continue debugging without a perhaps length re-build for example).